# How to select a range of columns with pandas rolling window function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to calculate a rolling sum of selected columns in my member-month structured healthcare dataset, *grouped* by member ID but *not* summing the member IDs, as well as excluding variables like gender from the rolling sum.

For example, using the following toy data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b':[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'c':[2,4,6,8,10,12]})
```

I've successfully calculated the rolling sums by member ID:

```
df_roll = df.groupby('id')['a','b','c'].rolling(window = 2).sum()
df_roll
```

so I'm almost there . . . but I haven't been able to select a range of columns as follows:

```
df_roll = df.groupby('id')['a':'c'].rolling(window = 2).sum()
df_roll
```

which is important since I have hundreds of columns in my real dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) with `loc` select the range columns you want to use then (2) `groupby` passing **df.id** and (3) apply de `rolling`

```
df.loc[:, 'a':'c'].groupby(df.id).rolling(window = 2).sum() \
                                 .reset_index() \
                                 .drop('level_1', axis = 1)

output:
    id  a    b      c
0   1   NaN  NaN    NaN
1   1   3.0  30.0   6.0
2   1   5.0  50.0   10.0
3   2   NaN  NaN    NaN
4   2   9.0  90.0   18.0
5   2   11.0 110.0  22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mask. Something like this.

```
mask=df.iloc[ : , 1: ]
df_roll = df[mask].groupby('id')['a':'c'].rolling(window = 2).sum()
```

On the other hand, if your range of columns is everything except the groupby column, you can just not give the range at all. Something like this

```
df_roll = df.groupby('id').rolling(window = 2).sum()
```